# ASP.NET Core - How to Inject WSDL Interface generated through dotnet-svcutil

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wsdl

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I generated WSDL SOAP Service as shown below:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-svcutil
dotnet-svcutil http://thirdpartyapi:3209/SchoolService/SchoolService?WSDL
```

Then I got this:

```
public interface SchoolServiceSEI
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://SchoolService.types.ws.gw.thirdpartyapi.com/SchoolServiceSEI/QueryStudent" +
        "IORequest", ReplyAction="http://SchoolService.types.ws.gw.thirdpartyapi.com/SchoolServiceSEI/QueryStudent" +
        "IOResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    QueryStudentResponse QueryStudent(QueryStudentRequest request);
    
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://SchoolService.types.ws.gw.thirdpartyapi.com/SchoolServiceSEI/QueryStudent" +
        "IORequest", ReplyAction="http://SchoolService.types.ws.gw.thirdpartyapi.com/SchoolServiceSEI/QueryStudent" +
        "IOResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<QueryStudentResponse> QueryStudentAsync(QueryStudentRequest request);
}

public partial class SchoolServiceSEIClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<SchoolServiceSEI>, SchoolServiceSEI
{
    
    public SchoolServiceSEIClient()
    {
    }
    
    public SchoolServiceSEIClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }
    
    public SchoolServiceSEIClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
    
    public SchoolServiceSEIClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
    
    public SchoolServiceSEIClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

   [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    QueryStudentResponse SchoolServiceSEI.QueryStudent(QueryStudentRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.QueryCustAccIO(request);
    }
    
    public QUERYSTUDENT_RES QueryStudent(QUERYSTUDENT_REQ QUERYSTUDENT_REQ)
    {
        QueryStudentRequest inValue = new QueryStudentRequest();
        inValue.QUERYSTUDENT_REQ = QUERYSTUDENT_REQ;
        QueryStudentResponse retVal = ((SchoolServiceSEI)(this)).QueryStudent(inValue);
        return retVal.QUERYSTUDENT_RES;
    }
    
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<QueryStudentResponse> SchoolServiceSEI.QueryStudentAsync(QueryStudentRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.QueryStudentAsync(request);
    }
    
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<QueryStudentResponse> QueryStudentAsync(QUERYSTUDENT_REQ QUERYSTUDENT_REQ)
    {
        QueryStudentRequest inValue = new QueryStudentRequest();
        inValue.QUERYSTUDENT_REQ = QUERYSTUDENT_REQ;
        return ((SchoolServiceSEI)(this)).QueryStudentAsync(inValue);
    }
}
```

Implementation:

public class StudentDetailService : IStudentDetailService
{
private readonly SchoolServiceSEIClient _client;
public StudentDetailService(
SchoolServiceSEIClient client
)
{
_client = client;
}
....
}

When I wanted to inject, I did it this way:

**DI:**

```
public static class DIServiceExtension
{
    public static void AddDependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<SchoolServiceSEIClient, SchoolServiceSEIClient>();  
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();
```

But I got this error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Configuration files are not supported. at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor() at SchoolServiceSEIClient..ctor() in C:\SchoolApp.Common\SchoolService.cs:line 149
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
```

I want to inject SchoolServiceSEI and SchoolServiceSEIClient

How do I implement DependencyInjection to inject **SchoolServiceSEI** and **SchoolServiceSEIClient**?

Comment: @YongShun - Kindly assist. I've tried all ways but no solution